# How to create Flink table with avro schema where all columns are inferred from schema

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am following https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/table/formats/avro/  to create tables in Flink.

```
CREATE TABLE user_behavior (
  user_id BIGINT,
  item_id BIGINT,
  category_id BIGINT,
  behavior STRING,
  ts TIMESTAMP(3)
) WITH (
 'connector' = 'kafka',
 'topic' = 'user_behavior',
 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
 'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
 'format' = 'avro'
)
```

However my avro schema has too many fields (100s of columns). Specifying each field is time consuming. Is there any way where Flink can infer from schema and create a column for each field automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the way to infer SQL schema from Avro schema automatically.

This can help you:

```
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroSchemaConverter
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Schema
 
val s = AvroSchemaConverter.convertToDataType(your_shema_json)
val schema = Schema.newBuilder().fromRowDataType(s).build()

println(schema)
```